# Multirow and align in TeX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

People help. There is a table, I can not even in the center (vertically and horizontally)
Field: Check item, Note, Not cheked, Supply Voltage - They're not in the middle (horizontal)
A Note and Check item and should be centered vertically align

[Code][1]

```
\begin{small}
\begin{longtable}{|M{25mm}|M{17mm}|M{17mm}|M{22mm}|M{20mm}|M{20mm}|M{22mm}|}  

\hline
\multirow{3}{25mm}{  Check item}                      & 
\multicolumn{2}{M{34mm}|}{ Device \mbox{IMEI.123456.12345}}       & 
\multicolumn{3}{M{62mm}|}{ XXX}               & 
\multirow{3}{22mm}{ Note} \\ \cline{2-6}                  &                           

\multirow{2}{15mm}{  norm}                                    & 
\multirow{2}{17mm}{  item number technique}                   & 
\multicolumn{1}{M{22mm}|}{ normal conditions}                 & 
\multicolumn{1}{M{20mm}|}{ plus 50 °С}                        & 
\multicolumn{1}{M{20mm}|}{ minus 20 °С}                           & 
\\ \cline{4-6}

&&& \multicolumn{3}{M{62mm}|}{  Supply voltage}  &
\\ \cline{4-6}
&&& \multicolumn{1}{M{22mm}|}{ 2,2 V}                         &
\multicolumn{1}{M{20mm}|}{ 5 V}                                   & 
\multicolumn{1}{M{20mm}|}{ 5 V}                                   & 
\\ \cline{1-7}
\endfirsthead

\endhead
\multicolumn{1}{|M{25mm}|}{ 1 Operability RS-232C} &
\multicolumn{1}{M{17mm}|}{Compliant}                         &
\multicolumn{1}{M{17mm}|}{5.2.1}                         &&  
\multicolumn{2}{M{40mm}|}{\multirow{2}*{not checked}} &
\\ \cline{1-4} \cline{7-7} 

\multicolumn{1}{|M{25mm}|}{ 2 Operability RS-485}  &
\multicolumn{1}{M{17mm}|}{Compliant}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{M{17mm}|}{5.2.2.1}                       &&   
\multicolumn{2}{M{40mm}|}{}                              &
\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|M{25mm}|}{ 3 Operability Ethernet} &
\multicolumn{1}{M{17mm}|}{Compliant}                         &
\multicolumn{1}{M{17mm}|}{5.2.2.2}                        &&&&
\\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{small}
```

Thank you very much! I like you very much cleared up! M {} I used array package, to center the word in the cell. This is not true?
I take into account your recommendations. And I turned on the one hand, and on the other - not very.
"Check item", "norm", "item number", "Note" moved to the left, "XXX" and "Compliant" went up.

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\begin{small}
\begin{longtable}{|C{25mm}|C{17mm}|C{17mm}|C{22mm}|C{20mm}|C{20mm}|C{22mm}|}  

\hline
\multirow{6}{25mm}{Check item}                                & 
\multicolumn{2}{C{34mm}|}{ Device \mbox{IMEI.123456.12345}}   & 
\multicolumn{3}{C{62mm}|}{ XXX}                               & 
\multirow{6}{22mm}{ Note} \\ \cline{2-6}                      &                           

\multirow{4}{15mm}{  norm}                                    & 
\multirow{4}{17mm}{  item number technique}                   & 
{ normal conditions}                                          & 
{ plus 50 °С}                                                 & 
{ minus 20 °С}                                                & 
\\ \cline{4-6}

&&& \multicolumn{3}{C{62mm}|}{Supply voltage}   &
\\ \cline{4-6}
&&                                              & 
{ 2,2 V}                                        &
{ 5 V}                                          & 
{ 5 V}                                          & 
\\ \cline{1-7}
\endfirsthead
\endhead

{ 1 Operability RS-232C}                              &
{Compliant}                                           &
{5.2.1}                                               &&  
\multicolumn{2}{C{40mm}|}{\multirow{4}*{not checked}} &
\\ \cline{1-4} \cline{7-7} 


{ 2 Operability RS-485}                               &
{Compliant}                                           &
{5.2.2.1}                                             &&   
\multicolumn{2}{C{40mm}|}{}                           &
\\ \hline

{ 3 Operability Ethernet}                             &
{Compliant}                                           &
{5.2.2.2}                                             &&&&
\\ \hline


\end{longtable}
\end{small}
```

[image]

```
\begin{longtable}{|M{25mm}|C{17mm}|C{17mm}|C{22mm}|C{20mm}|C{20mm}|C{22mm}|}  
\hline
\multirow{6}*{ Check item}                                    & 
\multicolumn{2}{M{34mm}|}{ Device \mbox{IMEI.123456.12345}}   & 
\multicolumn{3}{C{62mm}|}{ \centering XXX}                    & 
\multirow{6}*{Note} \\ \cline{2-6}            &                           
\multirow{3}*{norm}                                           & 
\multirow{3}{17mm}{ \centering item number technique}         & 
\multicolumn{1}{M{20mm}|}{ normal conditions}                                         & 
{ plus 50 °С}                                                 & 
{ minus 20 °С}                                                & 
\\ \cline{4-6}
&&& \multicolumn{3}{C{62mm}|}{\centering Supply voltage}   &
\\ \cline{4-6}
&&                                              & 
{ 2,2 V}                                        &
{ 5 V}                                          & 
{ 5 V}                                          & 
\\ \cline{1-7}
\endfirsthead
\endhead
{ 1 Operability RS-232C}                              &
{Compliant}                                           &
{5.2.1}                                               &&  
\multicolumn{2}{P{40mm}|}{\multirow{3}*{\centering not checked}} &
\\ \cline{1-4} \cline{7-7} 
{ 2 Operability RS-485}                               &
{Compliant}                                           &
{5.2.2.1}                                             &&   
\multicolumn{2}{P{40mm}|}{}                           &
\\ \hline
{ 3 Operability Ethernet}                             &
{Compliant}                                           &
{5.2.2.2}                                             &&&&
\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{small}
\clearpage
\SetEmptyPage
\end{document}
```

He made another small table. And here's what happens: The combined row is not aligned to the center, and moved to the left. Where am I wrong?

[image]

```
\begin{longtable}{|C{40mm}|C{40mm}|C{40mm}|C{40mm}|}
\caption{ } \label{instr:3} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{40mm}|}{Name of a power-supply circuit} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{40mm}|}{Power-supply circuit tension} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{40mm}|}{Current of consumption of a cell, А} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{40mm}|}{ Restriction on current, А}       \\\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{|p{160mm}|}
{\centering {Source PU1}} \\ \hline
<<5Ва>> & 5 В & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
<<5В>>  & 5 В & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|p{160mm}|}   {\centering{Source PU2}} \\ \hline
<<2,7В>> & 2,2 & 1,2 & 2,2 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Please insert the code to your question. I am not going to open external links. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is incomplete, so I had to make some guesses. I guessed that `M{...}` is an `m{...}` column.

Let's take the "Check item" as an example. Although it should span 3 logical rows, if you look at the output you will see that it occupies 6 physical rows. As multirow doesn't know how tall your rows are, you have to specify `\multirow{6}` to get it vertically centered.

**NOTE**: You have a lot of specs like `\multicolumn{1}{|M{25mm}|}` in a column that already has `|M{25mm}|` as its specification. This makes no sense, it just makes the table more complicated.
As for the horizontal centering, there are two ways.
(1) add `\centering`.

```
\multirow{6}{25mm}{\centering Check item}
```

(By the way, if you have a recent version of `multirow` (version 2.0 or higher) you don't have to repeat the `25mm` but you can write `=`)
(2) Put it in a `c` column:

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{6}{*}{Check item}}
```

You can do the same for the other entries, just count how many physical rows there are in each case.

With the "not checked" entry there is another problem, even when you make it

```
\multirow{4}*{not checked}}
```

The problem is, the reference point in that row is the second line of the first cell in that row, because you have used `m{...}` columns. This means the baseline (reference point) of the row is the last line. If you count from this line there are only 3 physical rows. so you need

```
\multirow{3}*{not checked}}
```

I have no idea why you want to use `m{...}` columns; often this is done because its function is misunderstood. I would advise to use `p{...}` columns and go for `\multirow{4}`.
And to get horizontal centering:

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}*{not checked}}
```

The `\centering` command doesn't work with `*` as width specifier; you would have to give the actual width, or `=` with a recent `multirow`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I like you very much cleared up! M {} I used array package, to center the word in the cell. This is not true?
I take into account your recommendations. And I turned on the one hand, and on the other - not very.
"Check item", "norm", "item number", "Note" moved to the left, "XXX" and "Compliant" went up.

Comment: Use `\multirow{6}{*}{Check item} `, `\multirow{4}{*}{norm}` `\multirow{4}{17mm}{\centering  item number technique}`, `\multirow{6}{*}{ Note}`. Compliant can be moved by changing the first column specifier to `M{25mm}`. And XXX can be moved by changing the entry to the left of it to `\multicolumn{2}{M{34mm}|}{Device \mbox{IMEI.123456.12345}}`.

Comment: I just saw that changing the first column to `M` moves "not checked. Compensate it with `\multicolumn{2}{C{40mm}|}{\multirow{3}*{not checked}}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Three days of searching for the cause. Do I understand correctly that if a word is short, the multirow {x} *, and if a few lines, the multirow {x} {25mm}?
And this time - Device, XXX and Supply Voltage visually shifted to the left? This is due to what?

Comment: And yet, if I change the Device Type M, then why change and XXX? It's different cell? How are they related?

Comment: Every cell is vertically aligned relative to the other cells in the same row, so they influence each other. The aligning is so that the "baselines" of the cells are on the same level. A `p{}` cell has its baseline on the first row, so then the other cell is at the same height as the first row. A `m{}` cell has its baseline in the vertical center of the text, so then the next cell aligns with the center of it.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this approach, if I have a single cell multiple lines of text, and the second one line (and I want it to align vertically), I need to specify the second line as a multirow and ask for her m {} ?

Comment: No. You can choose between two possibilities: (1) Put the multi-line text in `m{}` and leave the single-line text alone. (2) Put the multi-line text in `p{}` and put the single-line text in `\multirow`. If you combine `m{}` for the multi-line text with `\multirow` for the single-line text, it probably will not be positioned correctly. I think I will have to put something about this in the `multirow` documentation.

Comment: He made another small table. And here's what happens: The combined row is not aligned to the center, and moved to the left. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You should make that `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Source PU1}` and the same for the other one.

Comment: The error you made was thinking that the table is 160mm wide (4*40mm). But that is not true. You forgot the inter-column space. But using `c` is better, because it is independent of the width of the table.